# postfix header_checks using regexp proper setup

Tags: postfix, regex, replace, smtp-headers

I just can't seem to figure out why header_checks are not being evaluated.
I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, postfix 2.7, dovecote, spamassasin, clamav, amavis.

I add following line to /etc/postfix/main.cf :

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

And here is header_checks :

```
/From: .*/ REPLACE From: noreply@valid.mydomain.com
```

To test out regexp :

```
#postmap -q "From: <werwe>" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

which evaluates correctly and give me return output of :

```
REPLACE From: noreply@valid.mydomain.com
```

However, when I try to send email from commandline or from php webpage, postfix will not replace the From header.  I'm stumped.

I want to rewrite all outgoing emails:

```
From: Confirmation Email<webapp@invalid.mydomain.com>
```

-- changed to --

```
From: Confirmation Email<noreply@valid.mydomain.com>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved - Following line in /etc/postfix/master.cf was causing conflict :

```
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=
#   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks  //commented this line out
```