# Postfix "header_checks" is insane for me to accomplish

Tags: postfix, smtp-headers

I'm trying to **REJECT** an email with a certain phrase in the **SUBJECT (e.g. "quota limit")** using **Postix 2.9.6**. Following the postfix's documentation I realized postfix handles this info by checking the header. So **header_checks** is the attribute designated for checking headers in the email. Knowing this I added this line in my **main.cf** file:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/acl/header_checks/regexp
```

and the regexp:/etc/postfix/acl/header_checks/regexp fle contains:

```
/^Subject.*quota limit.*/  REJECT "SPAM ID:HeaderChecks01  Possible SPAM"
```

Following I validated the setting using (see **quota limit** in the subject):

```
postmap -q "Subject:squota limitjk" regexp:/etc/postfix/acl/header_checks/regexp
```

and I got:

```
REJECT "SPAM ID:HeaderChecks01  Possible SPAM"
```

It works!! Any message with this **quota limit** phrase in the subject should be automatically **REJECTED**. The thing is **it's not**.
Then I checked the official documentation for postfix regarding to header_checks in here: [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)
. Apparently I'm doing things right. **Why isn't this working??**
Before posting this I noticed there are previous questions in this great site (serverfault) **regarding this very same problem** and all of them without an accurate answer. You can check them here:
[Postfix header_checks not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/739130/postfix-header-checks-not-working) and [Postifx header_checks not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/806535/postifx-header-checks-not-working)

For a more close-to example I copied to a local file a piece of plain text from a real (not real domain included) SPAM email and did the same postmap -q check and got the same result. So doesn't seems to be a regexp problem at all. The text is this (see **quota limit** in the subject):

```
Reply-To: j.p.monfort.accomplish.delivery@timetelegram.info
Message-ID: <0f12fc934ada9939316f6986001319ff@timetelegram.us>
From: "ACCOMPLISH DELIVERY"
<j.p.monfort.accomplish.delivery@timetelegram.us>
To: <ielena@udomain.com>
Subject:=?windows-1252?Q?A_Spequota limitiversi_Aria_Pro._cia?=
<asdqtext to fill>
```

Last but not least I tried changing **header_checks** by **smtp_header_checks**, **mime_header_checks**, **smtp_mime_header_checks**, **milter_header_checks** and even **nested_header_checks** (just in case) and got nothing. I also checked for a receive_override_options param in the master.cf file and couldn't find it so there is no header_checks overridden.

**To point out**: Below **header_check**s I have **smtp_body_checks** and any email with the phrase "quota limit" is actually being rejected without any problem. It's only this attribute per se.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to my post lies here: [-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks](https://serverfault.com/questions/457953/postfix-header-checks-using-regexp-proper-setup/838989?noredirect=1#comment1073100_838989)

I just added the line **-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks** to my master.cf file **without a comment** and voilá. So far I have being doing what I wanted to in the beginning. I guess this entire post should be deleted or marked as duplicated.