# Postifx header_checks not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I have the main.cf config:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

And the `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/^Subject:.*viagra.*/i DISCARD
/^Subject:.*pills.*/i DISCARD
/^Subject:.*f\*ckbuddy.*/i DISCARD
/^Subject:.*f\*ckfriend.*/i DISCARD
/^Subject:.*f\@ck.*/i DISCARD

/^From:.*viagra.*/i DISCARD
```

Notice I have added the `/i` to make case insensitive. Not sure if it allows this?

I have tried sending emails from a hotmail to my server with pills in the subject but still no luck! Also is there a return to sender method instead of `DISCARD`?

Comment: Try to remove `/i` from patters. That worked for me (https://serverfault.com/a/967745/64579)

Answer (score 8):

If `postmap -q "<put test header here>" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` is correctly returning DISCARD (or the appropriate action for the match) but postfix is not actually performing said action, then there is probably a `receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks` somewhere in `main.cf` or `master.cf` that is turning off the header checks. In the `master.cf` file, it would be a `-o` option in one of the service configuration entries.

There are 4 options for `receive_override_options`:

> - no_unknown_recipient_checks
>     Do not try to reject unknown recipients (SMTP server only). This is typically specified AFTER an external content filter.
> - no_address_mappings
>     Disable canonical address mapping, virtual alias map expansion, address masquerading, and automatic BCC (blind carbon-copy) recipients. This is typically specified BEFORE an external content filter.
> - no_header_body_checks
>     Disable header/body_checks. This is typically specified AFTER an external content filter.
> - no_milters
>     Disable Milter (mail filter) applications. This is typically specified AFTER an external content filter.

The `no_address_mappings` options will typically be located in `main.cf` while the other options, in `master.cf`

> The "-o receive_override_options" overrides main.cf settings to avoid duplicating work that was already done before the content filter. These options are complementary to the options that are specified in main.cf

Source: [Postfix After-Queue Content Filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html)

Comment: This is unfortunately not working for me. I have followed all the instructions. I had the receive override options only set to the listener that is executed AFTER dkim proxy check. I still tried to disable every and reload postfix, but postmap returns nothing even with the key trigger word

Answer (score 1):

- `regex:` and `pcre:` patterns are case-insensitive by default. However, the `i` flag should work.
- You can use `REJECT` instead of `DISCARD` to inform the sender.
- Did you use `postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks` and reloaded postfix?
- You can test regexes online at many sites. http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm allows POSIX regexes.
- If available, using `pcre` regexes is usually faster then using the Posix implementation with `regexp:`. Use `header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks`
- What are the log files saying?

Comment: The postmap is not needed for pcre, but a postfix reload

Answer (score 1):

In the *header_checks(5) manual page*, there is this paragraph which says that for a while now the default for all regular expressions is to view them as case insensitive:

> COMPATIBILITY
>         With Postfix version 2.2 and earlier specify "postmap -fq" to query a table that contains case sensitive patterns. By  default,  regexp: and pcre: patterns are case insensitive.

So adding a flag to your regular expression would not fix your problem.

As others have mentioned, your first step is to verify that it works with a:

```
postmap -q "<string to test--i.e. Subject: Viagra>" /etc/postfix/header_checks.re
```

The output is going to be the action for the line. (`DISCARD` in your case)

If that works, you may be missing the line to include the header or a line that prevents the inclusion as others have mentioned.

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.re
```

Since you say you have that line there, the latter much be the problem.

Note that I have a `.re` extension. I don't think that matters, but it may be a good idea to have some kind of extension to know what the file contains.

Comment: Interesting. I am getting the desired result when invoking `postmap -fq` but nothing with `postmap -q`. What is strange is that I expected the opposite to be true. I mean, even if all my patters are `/i`, a case insensitive search (default) should return more results than a full case search (-f flag). Maybe I should post another dedicated question

Comment: In the docs I see this about `-f`: _With  Postfix  version 2.3 and later, this option has no effect for regular expression tables. There, case folding is controlled by appending a flag to a pattern._ So the `-f` has an effect if you have a version of Postfix prior to 2.3 by forcing everything to lowercase before the test.

Answer (score 0):

As **@HZC** says it could be an **-o receive_override_options** issue. I had the same problem here: [My issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/838958/postfix-header-checks-is-insane-for-me-to-accomplish-duplicated) and solved it following the post [postfix header_checks using regexp proper setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/457953/postfix-header-checks-using-regexp-proper-setup/838989?noredirect=1#comment1073100_838989). My case was a **REJECT** instead **DISCARD**. You use DISCARD in case you want to cheat spammer, the spammer won't receive any notification. For more info about this you can visit [this link](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) and see the **REJECTS ACTIONS** section.

DISCARD estructure:

```
              DISCARD optional text...
              Claim successful delivery and silently discard the message.  Log
              the optional text if specified, otherwise log a generic message.
```