# Postfix's header checks not working as expected

Tags: postfix, spam-filter

This question continues from [this identical](https://serverfault.com/questions/806535/postifx-header-checks-not-working) but focuses on another aspect of detail: the Postfix testing tool and the different options.

As the OP of the linked question, to prevent spam, and specifically, [compromised password extortions](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2019/jan/17/phishing-email-blackmail-sextortion-webcam), I have tried to block mail that contains my *pwned* old password as a means of chaffing.

*Supposed* the hacked password was... `P@ssw0rd`, here is what I have done:

I have created a regex rule in `/etc/postfix/header_checks`

```
/^Subject: .*P@ssw0rd.*/i REJECT I know you are scamming me
```

Then re-checked main.cf

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

According to the answers to the linked question, I double checked the master.cf for options that override the header checks. Since I use `dkimproxy`, which runs after `smtp` but before delivery, I had the `no_header_checks` option only on the dkim completion listener (port 10028 as recommended by manuals). I also tried to comment.

Now the test. If I pick an extortion email displaying my `P@ssw0rd` and push it to postconf I get different results. Please note the regex is flagged case insensitive

```
# postmap -q "Subject: Videos of you - P@ssw0rd" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
# postmap -fq "Subject: Videos of you - P@ssw0rd" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
DISCARD I know you are scamming me
```

The above example also worked with the magic *blue pill*

So I am stuck with this. I have read the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/940635/64579) by [Alexis Wilke](https://serverfault.com/users/62773/alexis-wilke) and learned that Postfix by default uses case **insensitive** comparison. Wow, I don't care about the case, I specified `/i` flag.

And [regexpal](https://regexpal.com) successfully finds the subject line when I put the headers into it.

Question: **what** is not working here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to not use the flag "i" to make it case insensitive indeed. From the manual, https://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html:

```
       i (default: on)
              Toggles  the case sensitivity flag. By default, matching is case
              insensitive.
```

The default is to be case insensitive, adding the flag "i" toggles it to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As with [speaking with a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), I found the solution myself while investigating and writing the question.

Removing the `/i` (case insensitive) flag from the header_checks file worked like a charm

Regex becomes `/^Subject: .*P@ssw0rd.*/ REJECT I know you are scamming me`

Waiting a few hours to see real mail being rejected in production. I won't wait long.